# Move/Rename Experience Editor 'Edit component properties' button

Tags: experience-editor

In specific instance, I prefer to make use of rendering parameters when creating a Sitecore rendering.  However, our content authors find it's placement and button description unintuitive.

[image: Edit component properties button]

I see that these buttons are configured in the `core` database at the following path: `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Default Rendering Buttons`.  Editing the button's `Header` field and order in the folder does not appear to affect the display in Experience Editor.  Is there any way to rename the 'Edit component properties' button and move it out of the 'More' dropdown, into the main toolbar?

Comment: Are you on the correct language when you chsne the `Header`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have already found, that button is defined by the `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Default Rendering Buttons/Properties` item in the core database.  To make that button appear in the main toolbar, change the Type field so there is no selection rather than the default `Common`.  Changing the Header field should modify the text when you have Type set to common.  When it appears in the toolbar, there is no text on the button, but you can change the tooltip field to change what shows when you hover over it.

As an alternative to globally changing this button, you could also copy the button under the Custom Experience buttons folder, modify it as needed and then select it for only the renderings you really need it on.